# Add an attribute with a value in its td tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with adding an attribute to  tag in table.

I have a loop which output an image an checkbox. (see picture below). when user click the first, it enables should enable the next checkbox to be enabled.

I would like user to click first image, than second than third and so on. I do not want user to click any image random.

**It works if i get rid of `<td>` tags. SO my problem is `<td>` tags**

[image: view image]

**HTML**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
   <?php
     $count = 1;
     for($x=0; $x < 5; $x++){
   ?>

   <td>
     <div class="thumb">
       <label for="image <?php echo $count;?>"><img class="img" src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image <?php echo $count;?>" name="tick" value="0" />
     </div>
   </td>

    <?php 
      $count++; }
    ?>

 </table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
 $(function() {

 var imageSelector = 'input[type="checkbox"][name="tick"]'; 
 $(imageSelector)
.on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if($this.is(':checked')) {
    $this
      .nextAll(imageSelector)
      .first()
      .removeAttr('disabled')
      .removeAttr('checked');
    return;
  }

  $this
    .nextAll(imageSelector)
    .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
    .removeAttr('checked');
})
.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
.removeAttr('checked')
.first().removeAttr('disabled');

});
</script>
```

How I can add attribue to `<td>` tags

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and paste HTML and JavaScript only in a [mcve]

Comment: _“How I can add attribue to <td> tags”_ – `td` elements do not have a `disabled` attribute. Even if you set it, it won’t _achieve_ anything.

Comment: Great. If i remove  <td> tags it all works. That's why i was thinking like that. How can I change my selector so user can only click the first image, than the second, than the third and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version if I understood you correctly.

PS: I suggest you do not have spaces in the ID

```js
$(function() {

  var imageSelector = 'input[type="checkbox"][name="tick"]';
  $(imageSelector).on('click', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      if (this.checked) {
        $this.closest("td").next("td")
          .find(imageSelector)
          .prop('disabled', false)
          .prop('checked', false);
      } else { // uncheck and disable the following checkboxes
        $this.closest("td").nextAll("td").each(function() {
          $(this).find(imageSelector)
            .prop('disabled', true)
            .prop('checked', false);
        });
      }
    })
    .prop('disabled', 'disabled')
    .prop("checked", false)
    .first().prop('disabled', false);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="thumb">
        <label for="image1"><img class="img" 
   src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image1" name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="thumb">
        <label for="image2"><img class="img" 
   src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image2" name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="thumb">
        <label for="image3"><img class="img" 
   src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image3" name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="thumb">
        <label for="image4"><img class="img" 
   src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image4" name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="thumb">
        <label for="image5"><img class="img" 
   src="http://s5.tinypic.com/30v0ncn_th.jpg"/></label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chk " id="image5" name="tick" value="0" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```